# Only join if field exists

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have these 2 tables.

Table *una*:

```
| id | word | desc |
```

Table *match*:

```
| id | word | review |
```

Table *una* has several thousands rows, table *match* will eventually have the same size as *una* but currently has very only a few rows.

What I want is to `SELECT` all rows from *una*, BUT, don't show rows that have a word that also exist in *match* AND are set as `review = 0`.

Do I need to use `IF EXISTS (....)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want SQL along this line of:

```
SELECT * FROM una WHERE word IN (
  SELECT word FROM una
  MINUS
  SELECT word FROM match WHERE review = 0
)
```

Update: improved:

```
SELECT * 
FROM una 
WHERE word NOT IN (
  SELECT word 
  FROM match 
  WHERE review = 0
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select u.*
from una u
     left join match m on u.word=m.word
having m.word is null
```

Comment: You want `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`. This is called an anti-join.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Good point, that will make the query run, but the results are not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @RacilHilan, it's a tough concept for some, but this is not only a solution, it's the better solution. An anti-join generally has better performance than a subquery.

Comment: @MarcusAdams OK, perhaps you can educate us all about the concept if you wish, but that was not my point. Regardless of the performance, this query does not return what the OP asked for. Read the question and requirements again. Where did the `review = 0` requirement go? I apologize if I'm missing something here, but you're debating the performance of something that does not fulfil the requirements. As it stands now, the accepted answer is the only correct one.

Comment: @RacilHilan, you're only now mentioning this. It's easy to overlook or forget that part of the requirement. It's always good to be clear, not coy.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Well, I clearly said "the results are not what the OP asked for", but that's OK. I agree that it is easy to overlook something while we're trying to provide quick and good answers to the questions, which is why we are here to guide and learn from each other. Perhaps you can post a correct answer so we can vote for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM una AS u
WHERE u.word NOT IN (SELECT word FROM match)
AND u.review = 0
```

**EDIT** - Sorry this is for TSQL, I don't know if its the same for Mysql.

Comment: You haven't used any TSQL-specific feature/function, so your query is pure SQL and will run in all databases.

Comment: Ah brilliant, I thought I would put the comment just in case I got marked down.

Comment: However, you forgot the second condition that OP asked for, that is `review = 0`. Otherwise, your answer could've been the accepted one since you were the first one to post it.

Comment: Cheers I just noticed that. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, but you added it in the wrong spot. Just move it to inside the brackets... Ah, and don't forget to appreciate the guidance. ;)